# Warning: Division by zero PHP

Tags: php

I get this error:
Warning: Division by zero in /home/twd/domains/twd.lt/public_html/Vka/php111u.php on line 13
100 (899 lines of this error up to number 999)

In this php code:

```
for ($x = 100; $x <= 999; $x++)
{
    $a = bcdiv ("x", "100");
    $b = bcdiv ("x", "10");
    $c = bcmod ("b", "10");
    $d = bcmod ("x", "10");
    $e = a + c + d;
    if ($x % $e == 0) // line 13
    {
        echo $x;
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: ANd what is your problem? `var_dump($a,$b,$c,$d,$e)`

Comment: why are you using `"x"` instead of `$x`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your a, b, c, d are zeroes so their sum `$e` is zero too. Therefore you're trying to find  `$x % 0`. The wrong approach is `bcdiv ("x", "100");` (and others) because you use string `"x"` instead of using value of `$x`. Also you use `$e = a + c + d`. A,C, and D are not constants, so you need add `$` in order to get values of correspond variables. Right code:

```
for ($x = 100; $x <= 999; $x++)
{
    $a = bcdiv ($x, "100");
    $b = bcdiv ($x, "10");
    $c = bcmod ($b, "10");
    $d = bcmod ($x, "10");
    $e = $a + $c + $d;
    if ($x % $e == 0) // line 13
    {
        echo $x;
        echo "</br>";
    }
}
```